# Running hello.py from within an Android Process

Tags: android, python

I'm trying to run a python script `hello.py` from within an Android Process.

Here are the steps I've followed:

1. I have procured python binaries and need linked libraries.
2. I have tested them and they are working in the terminal emulator.
3. I have added them to my asset folder and copied them to the private
   storage and made them executable.

But still I get the following error:

```
07-19 13:35:15.391 26991-26991/com.vibhinna.example I/System.out: Here is the standard output of the command:
07-19 13:35:32.001 26991-26991/com.vibhinna.example I/System.out: Here is the standard error of the command (if any):
07-19 13:35:32.001 26991-26991/com.vibhinna.example I/System.out: Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
07-19 13:35:32.001 26991-26991/com.vibhinna.example I/System.out: ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
07-19 13:35:32.001 26991-26991/com.vibhinna.example I/System.out: Current thread 0xb6f0dec8 (most recent call first):
```

Here is the code used to execute the file.

```
    String pyPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/usr/bin/python";
    String helloPath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/usr/bin/hello.py";
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pyPath, helloPath);

    Process proc = pb.start();
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    // read any errors from the attempted command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get this to work?

Comment: `Unable to get the locale encoding` `No module named 'encodings'`. Well... where is it?

Comment: @greenapps I have no idea. It's a simple helloworld.py.

Comment: The error  message does not depend on your script i think but on initializing python. You could as well supply the name of a non existing script i think.

Comment: @greenapps that's what I thought too. Any ideas what's affecting the initialization?

Comment: @greenapps found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was pure idiocy. After days of hair pulling I finally found out what went wrong. I didn't copy the `/usr/lib/python3.5` folder to the appropriate Android data folder.

This link was extremely helpful - [How does python find packages?](https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html)

Comment: Since Jul 19 went more than five hours ;-)!

Comment: @greenapps I dropped it for a while. Hehe. Edited.